# Rails redirect based on request

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Attempting to take a domain request and route it to a controller's index action.

The domain is stored in the database as `@site.host`.  A site is designated to a controller via @site.controller.
The application controller extracts the host

```
@site ||= if match = request.host.match(/.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$)/)
  domain = match[1]
  Site.find_by_host(domain)
end || Site.find(:first)
```

But the following is failing:

```
if request.url.split('?').first == ("https://" + @site.host)
  redirect_to :controller => @site.controller, :action => 'index'
end
```

Comment: You don't have to match on this stuff manually. Check out `request.protocol`, `request.host` , `request.url`, `request.port`, `request.host_with_port`, `request.domain`, `request.subdomain`

Comment: These were helpful.  However, I still needed to strip the everything before the domain to do the comparison with the db value.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is via database-generated session values which are then compared to the request and redirect accordingly

```
r_host = session[:host] + "/"
r_host_n = session[:host]
if request.url.split("//").last == (r_host || r_host_n)
  redirect_to :controller => session[:controller], :action => 'index'
end
```